# Show there exists an N such that $n\ge N$ implies $\int|f^+-\phi_n|\,d\mu<\epsilon/2$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\in L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$. This makes $\int f^+\,d\mu<+\infty$. Now, there exists a monotone increasing sequence of simple measurable functions $\phi_n$ that converge to $f^+$. By the monotone convergence theorem, we also have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \phi_n\,d\mu=\int f^+\,d\mu$$

How would one provide a precise symbolic argument that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that

$$\int \left|\,\,f^+-\phi_n\right|\,d\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: $L^?$ space? $L^1$? You need to specify if you use the $L$ notation just like that. I assume you mean $L^1$.

Comment: You need the hypothesis that $f > 0$ on a set of non-zero measure.

Comment: At this point (Chapter 5) in Bartle's Elements of Integration, if $X$ is a nonempty set, $\mathcal{X}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ is a measure defined on $\mathcal{X}$ (i.e., $\mu(E)\ge 0$ for any $E\in\mathcal{X}$, $\mu(\phi)=0$, and $\mu$ is countably additive). If $f\in L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$, that means that $f:X\to R$, $f$ is measurable, and $\int f^+\,d\mu<0$ and $\int f^-\,d\mu<0$. The integral of $f$ is defined as $\int f\,d\mu=\int f^+\,d\mu-\int f^-\,d\mu$. The space $L^p$ has not been discussed as yet.

Comment: @ncmathsadist : Why would you need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that hard ; since $|f^+ - \varphi_n| = f^+ - \varphi_n$, it suffices to find $N$ such that $\forall n \ge N$, 
$$
\int f^+ d\mu - \varepsilon/2 < \int \varphi_n d\mu \le \int f^+ d\mu.
$$
Use the fact that $\int \varphi_n d\mu \nearrow \int f \, d\mu$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I think it does help. Because $\int \varphi_n d\mu \nearrow \int f \, d\mu$, there exists an $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies that $\int f^+\,d\mu-\epsilon/2<\int \phi_n\,d\mu\le \int f^+\,d\mu$. Then $\int f^+\,d\mu-\int \phi_n\,d\mu<\epsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N$, which is saying the same thing as $\int(f^+-\phi_n)\,d\mu<\epsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N$, which is what I need.

Comment: @David :  Yes, indeed. Glad I helped